# Subscripting string literals in compile-time constants

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a string literal be subscripted in a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424647/can-a-string-literal-be-subscripted-in-a-constant-expression)

If I subscript a string literal, is the result a compile-time constant? In other words, is the following code valid?

```
constexpr char x = "a"[0];
```

GCC 4.7 says it is, but what does the standard have to say on this matter?

For the curious: I can't just write `'a'`, because the string literal is the result of the stringizing operator. Some compilers do have a charizing operator, but it's only an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking at 5.19 [expr.const]:

> 2 - A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it involves one of the following [...]
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with
>       a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression [ Note: a string literal (2.14.5)
>       corresponds to an array of such objects. —end note ] [...]

So the result of a string literal subscript operation may be converted to an rvalue in a core constant expression.

This is useful when defining constexpr operators for user-defined literals and user-defined string literals, although the variadic form can be more workable in some cases.