# Initializing with const array element

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, visual-c++, constants

Why does the compiler (VC++) not allow (error C2975)

```
const int HASH[] = {24593, 49157};
bitset<HASH[0]> k;
```

and what can I do to overcome this (initialize templates with constant values from array)?

Comment: And what *is* the error `C2975`? Not all of us know the VC++ compiler errors by heart.

Comment: Also, try using `constexpr` instead of `const`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyf0z2ka.aspx - basically it says that constant expressions should appear within the angle brackets.

Comment: `constexpr` doesn't seem to be available in VC++

Comment: related: [Difference between const and constexpr arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145567/difference-between-const-and-constexpr-arrays)

Comment: Which version of VC++?

Comment: VC++ 2012. It seems like it's impossible to make this work in VC++ 2012; it works with VC++ 2013 and Nov 2013 CTP apparently - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264644/constexpr-not-compiling-in-vc2013

Comment: Is that really what you want to do, BTW? That is, create a `std::bitset<N>` with 24593 bits? Did you mean to use `std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<int>::digits> k(HASH[0]);` which also wouldn't suffer from the problems you see?

Comment: Haha, yeah, for a hash table (24593 turns out to be prime). Well, thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local `const` object doesn't qualify as a constant expression but `std::bitset<N>` requires the non-type template parameter `N` to be a constant expression. A `const` integral object with an initializer does qualify as a constant expression. In all other cases you'll need `constexpr` (I don't know if MSVC++ supports `constexpr`). For example:

```
#include <bitset>

struct S { static int const member = 17; };
int const global_object = 17;
int const global_array[]  = { 17, 19 };
int constexpr global_constexpr_array[] = { 17, 19 };

int main()
{
    int const local = 17;
    int const array[] = { 17, 19 };
    int constexpr constexpr_array[] = { 17, 19 };

    std::bitset<S::member> b_member; // OK

    std::bitset<global_object>             b_global;                 // OK
    std::bitset<global_array[0]>           b_global_array;           // ERROR
    std::bitset<global_constexpr_array[0]> b_global_constexpr_array; // OK

    std::bitset<local>              b_local;           // OK
    std::bitset<array[0]>           b_array;           // ERROR
    std::bitset<constexpr_array[0]> b_constexpr_array; // OK
}
```

All that said, are you sure you really want to have a `std::bitset<N>` with the number of elements specified by the array? If you are actually interested in the bits of the value, you'd rather use something like this:

```
std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits> k(HASH[0]);
```

Comment: So it's not possible in VC++... oh well. Thanks for the answer! (and yes I did want 24593 bits)