# Constexpr function returning member of union: g++ vs. clang++: no diagnostics vs. error

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, unions, type-punning

Consider this code:

```
typedef union { float v; unsigned u; } T;
constexpr T x = { .u = 0 };
constexpr float f(void)
{
        return x.v;
}
```

Is this code valid?

Invocations:

```
$ g++ t506a.cpp -c -std=c++20 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>

$ clang++ t506a.cpp -c -std=c++20 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
t506a.cpp:3:17: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression
      [-Winvalid-constexpr]
constexpr float f(void)
                ^
t506a.cpp:5:9: note: read of member 'v' of union with active member 'u' is not allowed in a
      constant expression
        return x.v;
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: This code exhibits undefined behaviour and, for `constexpr` a diagnostic is required by the Standard. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319606/10871073) covers it well, so I *think* this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @AdrianMole _This code exhibits undefined behaviour and, for constexpr a diagnostic is required by the Standard_ No, for such code, the standard places no requirement.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So what of the Standard citations given in the linked duplicates? Are they wrong?

Comment: @AdrianMole the citations are about constant expression **evaluation**. Do you see `f` being invoked?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Irrelevant. The code for the `f` function is ill-formed.

Comment: @AdrianMole _Irrelevant_ Your dup targets? Absolutely. _The code for the `f` function is ill-formed_ With no diagnostic required, [which means there are no requirements](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.compliance#2.3).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Just for information, g++ and clang have the same differences, even if the [function is invoked](https://godbolt.org/z/9hc1vv344).

Comment: @AdrianMole Those targets are not correct. While diagnosing UB during constant evaluation is required, there's no constant evaluation of `f` in the OP's program. In the demo you linked in your comment, the evaluation of `f` is at run-time, so there's no diagnostic required there either. I'm not able to find a duplicate target for this, so I'm voting to reopen. Please ping me if an appropriate target is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both compilers are correct, even though the code is ill-formed, because no diagnostic is required in the program you've shown. It's true that `f` can never be evaluated as a core constant expression, but in that case [dcl.constexpr#6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6) applies:

> **For a constexpr function** or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, **if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function** or constructor **could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression**, or, for a constructor, an evaluated subexpression of the initialization full-expression of some constant-initialized object ([basic.start.static]), **the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required**.

(emphasis mine)

Since no diagnostic is required, GCC is allowed to not diagnose this.

On the other hand, if you do attempt to evaluate `f` as a constant, e.g.

```
constexpr float a = f();
```

then it violates [expr.const#5.10](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.10):

> An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that is applied to a glvalue that refers to a non-active member of a union or a subobject thereof;

and indeed, [both GCC and Clang diagnose this error](https://godbolt.org/z/fbdGPrez9), as required during constant evaluation.

Comment: _then it violates expr.const#5.10_ How is it possible to violate anything when https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.compliance#2.3